# Eth Console Won't Start: Invalid Argument Console

Tags: cpp-ethereum, console

### Can't Use "Eth Console" Command upon Installing Eth with Spacebrew

Hi everyone, I'm learning how to create my own d'apps on the Ethereum blockchain as part of a Master's thesis research process. So far I've been taking tutorials with geth and Mist, but am now moving into Eth and Mix for the C++ implementation.

I've already successfully installed geth with spacebrew and can use it normally from the command line.

I just tried to install eth using the instructions from the [github](https://github.com/ethereum/guide/blob/master/getting_started.md) and was able to successfully compile using spacebrew.

However, when I try to run

```
eth console
```

as per the instructions, I keep getting the error, "Invalid Argument: console".

I've tried using

```
eth --console
eth -console
eth console --frontier
eth console --testnet
```

all with similar results, and have made sure to upgrade and update spacebrew.

I've looked all over for someone with a similar problem, but can't find anything in the forums.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Only `geth` has a javascript console.

If you want to connect to `eth` or `parity`, simply run them:

```
$ eth
```

Or:

```
$ parity --geth
```

And after that you can use geth to attach a console to the c++ or rust client, like that:

```
$ geth attach
```

The output will look like this:

```
$ geth attach
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: eth/v1.3.0/Linux/g++/Interpreter/RelWithDebInfo/27da2620/
coinbase: 0x00243db98c4182ebc1d5abd921f986814c3bd7b9
at block: 1719189 (Fri, 17 Jun 2016 08:18:45 CEST)
 modules: admin:1.0 db:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 shh:1.0 web3:1.0

>
```

Note the 3rd line, telling you that you just attached to an `eth` instance.

Answer (score 0):

ethconsole is one word, and seems to be a javascript interpreter.

eth on the other hand is a compiled, linked, and installed executable.  Both are launched from the command line (in linux at least), but the parameter contexts are different.

eth uses the standard-style unix 'switch' command parameters, but ethconsole requires a weird asynchronous (call-back loaded) object-style string with a brief error-handler subsection at the end.